# how to get livereload working for angular app?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

I am trying to run grunt livereload for a simple angular app. This is the part in the gruntfile:

```
watch: {
            livereload: {
                files: [
                    '*.{html,js}',
                    'static/{,*/}*.{css,js,png,jpg,gif,svg}'
                ],
                tasks: ['jshint'],
                options: {
                    livereload: LIVERELOAD_PORT
                }
            }
        },
```

All the files (js,html) are in the rootdirectory. When I run 'grunt server --force' I get an error that the page cannot be displayed? How can I fix this so livereload works?

Also when I run 'grunt server' I get:

```
Warning: Object function createServer() {
  function app(req, res, next){ app.handle(req, res, next); }
  merge(app, proto);
  merge(app, EventEmitter.prototype);
  app.route = '/';
  app.stack = [];
  return app;
} has no method 'static' Use --force to continue.
```

plunkr:http://plnkr.co/edit/PvxU4R

Comment: have you included livereload script in html?

Comment: Would you please clarify `grunt server`?  If this is a grunt task list, do the individual tasks work separately?

Answer (score 1):

Update your package.json and use the `0.11.0` version of grunt-contrib-connect. It should works.

Comment: Did you run npm install? Or remove your node_modules folder and run npm install.